# TSQL Recursive Query Update Temp Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures, recursion

I have a query that is recursively going through my employee ORG and getting a list of all people that report up to the VP. This query is working as intended:

```
DECLARE @pit AS DATETIME = GETDATE();

DECLARE @table TABLE (
    mgrQID     VARCHAR (64) ,
    QID        VARCHAR (64) ,
    NTID       VARCHAR (64) ,
    FullName   VARCHAR (256),
    lvl        INT          ,
    metadate   DATETIME     ,
    totalCount INT          );

WITH   empList (mgrQID, QID, NTID, FullName, lvl, metadate)
AS     (SELECT   TOP 1 mgrQID,
                       QID,
                       NTID,
                       FirstName + ' ' + LastName,
                       0,
                       Meta_LogDate
        FROM     dbo.EmployeeTable_Historical
        WHERE    QID IN (SELECT director
                         FROM   dbo.attritionDirectors)
                 AND Meta_LogDate <= @pit
        ORDER BY Meta_LogDate DESC
        UNION ALL
        SELECT   b.mgrQID,
                 b.QID,
                 b.NTID,
                 b.FirstName + ' ' + b.LastName,
                 lvl + 1,
                 b.Meta_LogDate
        FROM     empList AS a CROSS APPLY dbo.Fetch_DirectsHistorical_by_qid (a.QID, @pit) AS b)
-- Insert into the counts table
INSERT INTO @table (mgrQID, QID, NTID, FullName, lvl, metadate, totalCount)
SELECT   empList.mgrQID,
         empList.QID,
         empList.NTID,
         empList.FullName,
         empList.lvl,
         empList.metadate,
         '0'
FROM     empList
ORDER BY lvl
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10);
```

As you can see, I have a table column called totalCount which I set to `0` in the first recursive query.

I now have a second query that goes through all of the people in that temp table and finds the total direct reports up to them.

For example if a Director Had 3 Managers and Each Manager has 3 Employees it would be 12 people reporting up to the director; the 9 employees and the 3 managers.

This comes from the query below:

```
;WITH     a
AS       (SELECT mgrQID AS direct,
                 QID
          FROM   @table AS t
          WHERE  QID IN (SELECT QID
                         FROM   @table)
          UNION ALL
          SELECT a.direct,
                 t.QID
          FROM   @table AS t
                 INNER JOIN
                 a
                 ON t.mgrQID = a.QID)
--subtracting 1 because it is also counting the manager
SELECT   direct,
         count(*) - 1 AS totalCount
FROM     a
GROUP BY direct
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10);
```

**My question is...**

How can I update `@temp totalCount` with the count I get from the second query? QID and Direct are the 2 fields in common amongst the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
update t
set t.totalCount = a.count(*) - 1
from a
join @temp t
    on a.Direct = t.QID
group by a.direct, t.QID
option (maxrecursion 10)
```